How to configure MassTransit to get messages from Azure Event Hub, store fault and/or error message in RabbitMQ and correctly consume Fault<T>
I'm a newbie to MassTransit and for now I correctly configure MassTransit to get and consume messages of type "T" from Azure Event Hub, but a cannot view/consume Fault<T> messages when an exception is raised from Azure Event Hub Consumer. Below my Mass Transit Configuration:
 public static void ConfigureApplication(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
 {
     serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(x =>
     { 
         // THIS STATEMENT NOT TRIGGER/FIRE RELATED MyFaultConsumer
         x.AddConsumer<MyFaultConsumer>();  
    
         x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
         {
             cfg.Host("RabbitMQ_Host", "RabbitMQ_VirtualHos", h =>
             {
                 h.Username("RabbitMQ_Username");
                 h.Password("RabbitMQ_Password");
             });
             cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
             cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(configurator =>
             {
                 configurator.Exponential(
                     3000,
                     TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
                     TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                 );
             });

             cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
         });
    
         x.AddRider(rider =>
         {
             rider.AddConsumer<TransactionConsumer>();
             
             rider.UsingEventHub((context, k) =>
             {
                 k.Host("AzureEventHub_ConnectionString");
                 k.Storage("AzureStorage_ConnectionString");

                 k.ReceiveEndpoint("AzureEventHub_HubName","AzureEventHub_ConsumerGroup", e =>
                 {
                     e.UseRawJsonDeserializer(RawSerializerOptions.AnyMessageType, true);
                     e.ConfigureConsumer<TransactionConsumer>(context);
                 });
             });
         });
     });
 }

// THIS NEVER CALLED/TRIGGERED
public class MyFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault<MyClass>>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault<MyClass>> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyFaultConsumer ");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

// THIS ALWAY CALLED/TRIGGERED
public class TransactionConsumer: IConsumer<MyClass>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyClass> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TransactionConsumer");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

I try to follow MassTransit documentation but without any solution

Faults are not produced by Event Hubs nor Kafka topics. If you're unable to consume a message from an Event Hub, you'll need to figure out the logic of dealing with:

Expected failures, perhaps produce a business event on RabbitMQ, etc.
Unexpected failures, you may use retry middleware for transient faults blocking until the message is consumed successfully.

I'd suggest reviewing the error handling patterns outlined by Confluent as they are similar to Event Hubs and determine an approach that be suits your scenario.
